# developing for mobile computer with barcode reader

Tags: android, events, button, android-edittext, barcode-scanner

I've got [this mobile device](http://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-GB/Pages/Product.aspx?category=hand-held-mobile-computer&cat=HSM&pid=Dolphin7800A), it has a **barcode reader** and `SCAN button`. So, I've got no `EditTexts` on my `mainActivity`, but I want to get an event, when **barcode scanning ends**, and reсeive barcode value in `event's handler`.

Kinda way to do this is to place an `edittext` to the activity and bind a `textwatcher` to it, and when edittext's value changes, read it's value. But I have to do this on a simple screen without any inputs.

The `SCAN button` doesn't place any value, it seems to be starting another component, that reads a barcode and places value into an input field.

So, how do I get this without any inputs? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tried having an invisible EditText field?

```
<EditText
     ...
     android:visibility="invisible">
```

Comment: hey, sorry for delayed reaction, yes, I did, but it didn't help, even if I set focus manually.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used zxing library for barcode scan? If yes than you will get event in handleDecodeInternally function in CaptureActivity because that function called when barcode scanning ends. Also you can set your EditText in capture.xml and set value in handleDecodeInternally function.

Comment: thanks, I'll try this. I can't upvote your comment because of lack of reputation, but this seems to be a correct way to do what i want to do.